# Angular filter|formating with global settings (best practics)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are simple filter from shared library

```js
.filter('minutes2hm', function () {
    return function (min, apply) {
        if (apply === false) {
            return min;
        }
        var h = Math.floor(min / 60).toString();
        min = (min - (h * 60)).toString();
        return '' + '00'.substring(0, 2 - h.length) + h + ':' + '00'.substring(0, 2 - min.length) + min;
    };
```

And html

```html
<th>{{minutes-125 | minutes2hm: false}}</th> --> 125
<th>{{minutes-125 | minutes2hm: true}}</th> --> 02:05
```

I want move true|false to user settings

```html
<th>{{minutes-125 | minutes2hm}}</th>
```

```js
.filter('minutes2hm', function () {
    return function (min) {
        if (USERSettings.apply === false) {
            return min;
        }
        ...
    };
```

Which way is best practics for

- save user settings
- use user setting in filters

which allow share filter code beetween project in result?

Answer (score 1):

If shared filter is in use in different places then first of all create second custom filter with **different name**, next get user settings from service ( filters can use dependency injections ), and last one - call "old" filter in custom filter by `$filter` service, example usage:

```
app.filter('userMinutes2hm', function($filter,$userSettings) {
return function(min) {

    return $filter('minutes2hm')(min,$userSettings.apply); //use filter in filter with param from service
}
});
```

PS. I see that You have global variable `USERSettings`, it is wrong practice, create some service for user settings ( `$userSettings` ) like I showed above.

---

Summary: best practice is to use service with global settings instead of global variables outside angular. Services are singletons so can also store/save data, if You want to store data permanently then service can use for example localStorage for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why you using this below code? and what is the Use of the below code?

```
if (apply === false) { //and if (USERSettings.apply === false)
            return min;
        }
```

If you won't use filter, then don't call the filter on your `<th>`. Why you need pass `true|False`

So if you remove that code, then your `<th>` and result should be looks like this

```
<th>{{minutes-125 </th> --> 125
<th>{{minutes-125 | minutes2hm}}</th> --> 02:05
```

and filter code looks like

```
.filter('minutes2hm', function () {
    return function (min) {
               var h = Math.floor(min / 60).toString();
        min = (min - (h * 60)).toString();
        return '' + '00'.substring(0, 2 - h.length) + h + ':' + '00'.substring(0, 2 - min.length) + min;
    };
```

Comment: I want have one html template with <th>{{minutes-125 | minutes2hm}}</th> and allow user switch view globally 125 or 02:05